# Javascript method does not populate method (array)

Tags: javascript

Take the following class as an example:

```
function TestClass() {

  // public property
  this.testArray = [];

  // public function
  this.populateArray = function() {
    for (var y = 1; y <= 9; y++) {
      for (var x = 1; x <= 12; x++) {
        this.testArray[x + '-' + y] = true;
      }
    }
  };
}
```

When I call the `populateArray` method, it runs as expected, but it does not modify the `testArray` property.

I've tried pulling the method out and adding it via prototype, but that also does not work.

```
TestClass.prototype.populateArray = function() {};
```

The code that is calling the method is here:

```
var testClass = new TestClass();
testClass.populateArray();
```

Why is the method not populating the property?

Comment: How do you test whether the array is populated or not? The problem is probably that you are adding arbitrary properties to the array, not array elements. It seems you should use an object instead of an array. I.e. `var foo = []; foo.bar = 42; foo.length;` will result in `0` because `foo.bar` is not considered to be an array element. To avoid such a confusion, use an object (or better: `Map`) instead of an array.

Comment: You are using an _array_ but you are setting _object properties_ on it. Arrays in JavaScript are only number indexed. If you want to use string keys (e.g., what would in other languages be called a hash), you need to use an object: `{}`. You can set random properties on an array but it's _bad practice_, since they are in no way shape or form "official".

Comment: What did you expect the array to look like after calling that method?

Comment: Yeah, changing `this.testArray = [];` to `this.testArray = {};` fixed the issue. Thanks Felix!

Comment: You might want to think up a different name now for that property :)

Comment: @ScottJoudry Putting the data in an object in that manner will make it more difficult to iterate over. I suggest sticking with an array. That way you can iterate over x and y separately

Answer (score 0):

Array elements are stored using indexes.

```
var arr = [];

arr[1 + '-' + 2] = 2;
```

Here `arr.length` will be zero because `'1-2'` is not an array index.Here it is a stored as a property of the array object.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with the way you were assigning arrays, see the comments for explanations:

```
function TestClass() {

  this.testArray = [];


  this.populateArray = function() {
    for (var y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
      this.testArray.push([]); //Create 9 arrays
      for (var x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
        this.testArray[y].push([]); //Create 12 arrays for every 'y' array
        this.testArray[y][x] = true; //You were using a string to access an array value. You can only do that with objects
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you wanted to write I guess:

```
function TestClass() {

  // public property
  this.testArray = {}; // <-- Object!
  var self = this;     // Saving this (the context) of TestClass

  // public function
  this.populateArray = function() {
    for (var y = 1; y <= 9; y++) {
      for (var x = 1; x <= 12; x++) {
        self.testArray[x + '-' + y] = true; // Using self
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Also [here it is](https://jsbin.com/yubepabeko/edit?js,console) running.